# Real Roots of Complex Quadratic Equation - (Kasana's first example)

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

I recently bought H.S. Kasana's *Complex Variables*. It seems quite interesting, and a little harder for me than I had expected, though I should be able to get through it if I take my time.

Nevertheless, I am having some trouble with the very first example... It starts like this:

> **Under what conditions on complex constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, will the quadratic equation $z^2 + \alpha z + \beta = 0$ have (a) real roots, (b) one of the roots on the unit circle $|z| = 1$?**
>
> Suppose the quadratic equation has real roots, say $z = x$. Then,
>   $$x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;\;\; x^2 + \bar{\alpha} x + \bar{\beta} = 0$$
>   Eliminating x, ...

The first equation is simply the original, but where did the second one (with the conjugates) come from? At first I though they might both be valid because the real part is the same for both, but the imaginary part still isn't, so that's not it.

I understand the rest of the example fine, but I would love to understand why the second equation can be added, so that I could solve such a problem by myself in the future.

Thanks :)

Comment: He is just taking complex conjugates on both sides of the first equation. Also, $\overline{0}  = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the complex conjugation has this two properties:
$$\bar z+\bar w=\overline{z+w}$$
$$\bar z\bar w=\overline{zw}$$

So, if $x$ is a real root, we have $\bar x=x$ and
$$0=\bar 0=\overline{x^2+\alpha x+\beta}=\overline {x^2}+\overline{\alpha x}+\bar \beta=x^2+\bar\alpha x+\bar\beta$$

Comment: Thanks! I just realized he simply took the conjugate... I think the equations still looked so different to me, that it seemed like their roots might not be the same... Being silly

Answer (score 1):

Just complex conjugate
$$
x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0
$$
to get
$$
\overline{x^2 + \alpha x + \beta} = 
\overline{x^2} + \overline{\alpha} \overline{x} + \overline{\beta} = \overline{0} = 0.
$$
And since $x$ is real,
$$
x^2 + \overline{\alpha} x + \overline{\beta} = 0.
$$